# Unpack a tar archive generated by a shell command with Python tarfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I have a `nomad alloc exec` command kind-of like ssh that I am able to run tar on the other side and get stdout.

I want to copy multiple files from a process that outputs a tar archive to stdout. In shell this is called a tar pipe, typically `ssh server tar cf - file1 file2 | tar xf - -C destinationdir`. I would want to do the same in python, spawning a `subprocess` on the left side of the pipe and using `tarfile` for the right side instead of spawning a another `subprocess` or shell.

This is what I've tried:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import tarfile

os.system("echo 123 > /tmp/1 ; mkdir -p /tmp/dir")
sourcefile = "/tmp/1"
destinationdir = "/tmp/dir"
with subprocess.Popen([*"tar -cf - --".split(), sourcefile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as pp:
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=pp.stdout) as tf:
        tf.extractall(destinationdir)
```

However, this is not possible, because tarfile wants to seek stdout and it can't to (don't seek it!)

```
$ python3 ./test.py 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dev/shm/.1000.home.tmp.dir/./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    with tarfile.open(fileobj=pp.stdout) as tf:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 1630, in open
    saved_pos = fileobj.tell()
OSError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek
```

How can I extract tarfile output / input from a subprocess straight to a directory?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use `tarfile` in combination with `tar` command. You already have an archive but want to create a new one out of it using `-c`? Does not make much sense to me. In either case, you could directly pass `f` to the Popen call? Or not use `subprocess` and use `tf.extractall()` or other methods?

Comment: You can get at the underlying file object using `tf.fileobj` (so, `stdin=tf.fileobj`, for example), but I agree with the previous comment: I'm not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I want to copy files from the remote, I do not have a tar file. The tar file is created on the fly and then unpacked on the fly, like in shell  `ssh server tar cf - file1 file2 | tar xf - -C destinationdir`. This would translate to `subprocess.Popen("ssh server tar cf - file1 file2")` but I do not know how to read from a `Popen` into `tarfile` to extract data without creating temporary files. Sorry for explaining it poorly

Answer (score 0):

Given that your actual intent is to run a copy of `tar` on a remote server, this permits an easier approach:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import tarfile

remote_files = [ 'file1', 'file2' ]
remote_proc = subprocess.Popen([
      'ssh', 'server',
      f'tar -cf - {" ".join(shlex.quote(name) for name in remote_files)}'
  ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

with tarfile.open(fileobj=remote_proc.stdout, mode='r|') as tf:
    tf.extractall(destinationdir)
```

Some notes:

- **Using the `r|` mode** (instead of the default `r`) **tells tarfile that seeking is not permitted.**
- `ssh` concatenates all arguments it doesn't interpreted as intended for its own use, separated by spaces, into a string which it passes as a shell command over the wire.
  It's thus preferable to pass only a single string yourself, instead of assuming that the concatenation process will result in the string that you want (which it often doesn't, as this "join with spaces" process doesn't honor quotes/escaping/etc to generate a string that parses into the original list).
- Because there's a remote shell started by ssh, it's obligatory to quote filenames to ensure that they're correctly parsed by that remote shell, hence the use of `shlex.quote()`.